# Google Colab to Kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I tried to run a code in Kaggle Notebook, which I had run earlier in Google Colab without an issue. But in Kaggle I get the following issue. How to fix it? Thank you.

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(image_size[0], image_size[1], 3))

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Here I have tried to build the pre-trained MobileNetV2 model for a custom dataset using tensorflow and keras.

Issue:
[image]